# javascript regular expression replace in input form validation

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

When inputting a string with a format:

> the beginning `r` or `R`, then some non-digit letters, I want to
>   replace the string with `R`.

It's in this situation:

```
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^[rR]\D/g,'R')"
```

But it does not work.

Somebody can help me out? Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/scakouae/1/ ?

Comment: Post your possible inputs along with expected outputs

Comment: something like this `this.value.replace(/^[^r^R]/g,'R')`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny's jsfiddle *does* work for me (testing on Chrome). You don't even need the `g` modifier, since a regex which starts at `^` will match at most once (no multiple substitutions necessary).

Comment: `/^/` never requires the *g* flag, how many "start of strings" are there? ;-)

Comment: Please define "*it does not work*". What input did you supply? What result did you expect? What do you get?

Comment: @ArunPJohny's jsfiddle works fine. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
     onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^[rR]\D+/, 'R')";
```

See this DEMO:

```html
<input onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/^[rR]\D+/,'R')" />
```

Comment: Thanks, chsdk. It's what I want. And @ArunPJohny 's answer also works fine. Thank all of you.

Comment: Great, glad it helps.